# How to display the x -axis text in a tilted/rotate to 45 degree in Python Seaborn Subplots?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have the below the below three dataframes

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['JohnJohnJohnJohn','JuneJuneJuneJune','DanDanDanDan','JohnJohnJohnJohn','DanDanDanDan','DineDineDineDine','JuneJuneJuneJune','JohnJohnJohn'],columns =['Months'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['John_1John_1John_1','June_1June_1June_1','Dine_1Dine_1Dine_1','John_1John_1John_1','Dine_1Dine_1Dine_1','John_1John_1John_1'],columns =['Months'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['John_2John_2','Dine_2Dine_2','Dine_2Dine_2','John_2John_2','June_2June_2','John_2John_2'],columns =['Months'])
```

When displaying them in seaborn countplot, the x axis label gets over-write on each other. How can I rotate to 45 degree in display? I tried the below but doesn't work

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3)

sns.countplot(x='Months', data=df,order=df.Months.value_counts().index,ax=axes[0]).set(title='1D')
sns.countplot(x='Months', data=df1,order=df1.Months.value_counts().index,ax=axes[1]).set(title='2D')
sns.countplot(x='Months', data=df2,order=df2.Months.value_counts().index,ax=axes[2]).set(title='3D')
# axes.set_xticklabels(axes.get_xticklabels(), rotation=40, ha="right")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rotate the labels for all axes:

```
for ax in axes:
    ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
```